# "git add ." error fatal permission denied

Tags: file, github

Trying to upload some files to a repo. It worked for the last repo that I did, but now for some reason it's not working. Please help! :) Thanks :)

```
$ git add .
error: open("AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Application Cache/Cache/data_0"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Application Cache/Cache/data_0
fatal: adding files failed
```

Comment: What is your current directory before you run `git add .`? (Type `pwd`.) It looks like you're trying to add your home directory to Git, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you I forgot to change the directory :P. I'm new to all this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You are probably out of a git repo**: try to `cd` into you repo.

If you are really in the correct directory, you must change the `chmod` of your folder.